# Android: Spinner onItemSelect inflate another Spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner with which onItemSelect I need to open another Spinner based on the selection in the first.Here is the code...I am able to inflate the first spinner but on selecting an entry nothing happens

```
Spinner filterSpinner = new Spinner(SearchResultsActivity.this);
            filterSpinner.setPrompt("Filter By");
            ArrayAdapter<String> filterSpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchResultsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    filterSpinnerArray);
            filterSpinnerArrayAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            filterSpinner.setAdapter(filterSpinnerArrayAdapter);
            filterSpinner.performClick();
            filterSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new FilterItemSelectedListener());
```

and here is the code for the handling the spinner `onItemSelected`:

```
public class FilterItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        switch (pos) {
        case 0:

            Spinner filterBusSpinner = new Spinner(SearchResultsActivity.this);
            filterBusSpinner.setPrompt("Filter Buses By");
            ArrayAdapter<String> filterBusSpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchResultsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    filterByBusSpinnerArray);
            filterBusSpinnerArrayAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            filterBusSpinner.setAdapter(filterBusSpinnerArrayAdapter);
            filterBusSpinner.performClick();
            break;
        case 1:
            Spinner filterTimeSpinner = new Spinner(SearchResultsActivity.this);
            filterTimeSpinner.setPrompt("Filter By Time");
            ArrayAdapter<String> filterTimeSpinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    SearchResultsActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                    filterByBusSpinnerArray);
            filterTimeSpinnerArrayAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            filterTimeSpinner.setAdapter(filterTimeSpinnerArrayAdapter);
            filterTimeSpinner.performClick();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

to my best knowladge, a spinner won't open, unless it is drawn on the screen.
so before filterTimeSpinner.performClick(), you should attach the new spinner to some existing layout.

but, i've done something similer to your needs with a context menu.

i register a context menu to the spinner (which can be designed to look just like spinner rows if needed), and when an item is selected, i open the context menu. (same effect isn't it?)

hope it helps. 
 Vlad